# CodeIgniter Anchor error: URL not found on this server

Tags: php, codeigniter, anchor, codeigniter-2

I have been for hours to make a simple anchor link working without success.

My controller is

```php
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('template');
    }

    public function contact()
    {
        $this->load->view('contact');
    }        
}
```

My `template.php` view is basically a file with

```
<a class="menuhref"> <?php echo anchor('welcome/contact/','Contato')?> </a>
```

I also have a contact.php in the views directory.

My `config.php` is

```php
$config['base_url']   = 'localhost'; 

$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

When the `template.php` loads and I click in the link "contato" I would like to drive the system to the function `contact()` that would be responsible to open the page `contact.php`. However, I have got the following error:

> "/localhost/index.php/welcome/contact" was not found on this server

What is missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `base_url` config **MUST** contains the **protocol** and a **trailing slash** as well.

From the `config.php` file:

> URL to your CodeIgniter root. Typically this will be your base URL,
>   WITH a trailing slash:
>
> ```
> http://example.com/
> ```
>
> If this is not set then CodeIgniter will guess the protocol, domain
>   and path to your installation.

Hence, you could set the `base_url` as follows, or in this case simply leave it blank:

```php
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/';

# base_url should be absolute, If you've installed CI in sub-folder:
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/path/to/codeigniter_folder/';
```

**Side-note:** in order to use URL helper functions such as `anchor()`, **load the helper file** at first: `$this->load->helper('url');` *(or load the helper automatically via `autoload.php` config file).*

---

### Why does `base_url` config affect `anchor()` function?

[`anchor()`](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/helpers/url_helper.php#L143) function, [uses `site_url()`](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/helpers/url_helper.php#L147-L153) helper function to determine the URL address of the hyperlink.

And the [`site_url()`](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/helpers/url_helper.php#L45) itself, [uses two `base_url` and `index_page`](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/2.1-stable/system/core/Config.php#L256-L266) configs to create the URL address.

Hence if you assign a wrong value to `base_url` and/or `index_page` configs, the `anchor()` function won't work properly.

Comment: Dear @hashem-qolami thank you for your answer. The error changed! It is now "The requested URL /index.php/welcome/contact was not found on this server." It seems that I am using incorrectly anchor, since the url seems to be looking for a directory instead of a file.

Comment: @DanielTheRocketMan Please update the question with the current code you've used.

Comment: @DanielTheRocketMan The syntax of `anchor()` function is correct, but I just noticed you've entered the name of the Controller in Capitalized format: `anchor('Welcome/contact/','Contato')?>`. **Only** in the `anchor()` function: change the `Welcome` to `welcome` all in lowercase

Comment: thank u. Actually I tried both and return the same error. I am correcting the question. Does it mean the error happen before?

Comment: @DanielTheRocketMan Does `http://localhost/index.php/welcome/contact` work if you enter that directly into the address bar?

Comment: Thank you, @Hashem Qolami! The correct baseUrl should be $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/NetBeansProjects/SocialNetworkExCodeIgnitor/'. I have tried this before, but since there was the other error that you called my attencion (and I am also using NetBeans that is able run the open page), I was not able to see this. Now I undestand what is happening. I will remove the edit above and keep your answer as the answer of the question!

Comment: Hey you know what, you can use this code in your base path inside config.php and then you won't have to change anything even if your project is shifted to some other folder / server

    $root = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    $root .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
    $config['base_url'] = $root;